# Asp.Net core container isn't ignoring node_modules and won't start because of it existing

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose, dockerfile, dockerignore

I have an asp.net core project I am working on starting and I am getting everything setup for the local docker containers and an Angular app nested inside of the project. The app will launch perfectly fine if there isn't a `node_modules` folder. After installing my packages for Angular and running the container the app will never launch. I have tried messing with the `.dockerignore` and I cannot get the folder to get out of my builds.
[image: Node Modules folder included in builds]

`.dockerignore`:

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules*
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
```

`Dockerfile and Compose`:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FileConverter.Api/FileConverter.Api.csproj", "FileConverter.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FileConverter.Api/FileConverter.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FileConverter.Api"
RUN dotnet build "FileConverter.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FileConverter.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FileConverter.Api.dll"]

version: '3.4'

services:
  fileconverter.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}fileconverterapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FileConverter.Api/Dockerfile
```